# How to change transform.position code to Rigidbody.AddForce?

Tags: unity, c#

```
Vector2 vec = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
        vec = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(vec, 1);

        Vector3 camF = cam.transform.forward;
        Vector3 camR = cam.transform.right;

        camF.y = 0;
        camR.y = 0;
        camF = camF.normalized;
        camR = camR.normalized;

        transform.position += (camF * vec.y + camR * vec.x) * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;
```

That's how i do my movement, but i need to change it to Rigidbody.AddForce 'cause the way that i use right now makes my character doesn't collide with objects **perfectly.**

**Note:** What i mean with "perfectly" is, if you walk to the corner of walls, you can pass through it and that's the thing that i want to prevent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most drop-in solution is to convert your position to a velocity needed to reach that position, then accelerate yourself to that velocity:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    // Calculate your desired position however you like.
    Vector3 desiredPosition = GetDesiredPosition();

    // What velocity gets us there in one timestep?
    Vector3 desiredVelocity = (desiredPosition - transform.position)/Time.deltaTime;

    // If you want to preserve velocity on the y to let gravity accumulate, uncomment:
    // desiredVelocity.y = body.velocity.y;

    // Apply a sufficient impulse to hit reach that velocity.
    body.AddForce(desiredVelocity - body.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Though generally I'd advise thinking of your control as seeking a target velocity rather than teleporting to a target position. [I show an example of that style in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/166427/39518).

Comment: Okay i got it, it works, but how to incearese my movement speed?

Comment: By changing your desired position. You can also reduce the friction on your colliders' physics materials to reduce energy loss.

Comment: It works fine thank you so much

Comment: I found a bug, gravity is so low on my character how can i fix that?

Comment: I have an Isgrounded method btw incase if it helps

Comment: Take gravity into account when deciding on your desired position. Or, set `desiredVelocity.y = body.velocity.y` to let the acceleration due to gravity accumulate unchanged on the y axis.

Comment: I tried `desiredVelocity.y = body.velocity.y` but it can still float anyway. I calculate my target position like this: `targetPosition = (camF * vec.y + camR * vec.x) * MoveSpeed;` how can i calculate gravity here?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.